# Insert statement attempted to include a duplicate key

Tags: sql, database, oracle, syntax, syntax-error

Trying to run

```
INSERT INTO BOOKING_EXTRAS (BOOKING_ID, EXTRAS_, EXTRAS_PRICE) VALUES ('1','Phone call: 1.80','1.8');
```

in Oracle SQL Developer. Ive had it running but when I close it, then reopen it I get this error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
INSERT INTO BOOKING_EXTRAS (BOOKING_ID, EXTRAS_, EXTRAS_PRICE) VALUES ('1','Phone call: 1.80','1.8')
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (COURSEWORK_XE.BOOKING_EXTRAS_PK) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
       For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
       this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

how would I fix this? Its happening to every table I run!

Comment: Check the table, looks like table has a record with same primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either clear the tables or insert new information, a database doesn't want duplicate rows because that makes it impossible to find the correct rows later.

Comment: it's also very wrong. duplicates are fine UNLESS there is a unique constraint on a column (probably booking_id in your case)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if that **BOOKING_ID** (currently serves as primary key if I guess right) doesn't actually mean something for you, you can set it as AUTO INCREMENT in your schema, then afterwards you don't need to insert a value for BOOKING_ID, the system will automatically find a value which is not duplicate for you. This might save you a lot effort.

```
INSERT INTO BOOKING_EXTRAS (EXTRAS_, EXTRAS_PRICE) VALUES ('Phone call: 1.80','1.8');
```

Answer (score 1):

If your unique column is being populated by a sequence, check to make sure that your sequence has the same 'last value' as your highest-value unique column.
I just encountered a problem where the sequence had a 'last value in' that was much lower than the highest value in my unique column. The DBA ran a script to update the sequence to what the number should have been, and my error went away.

Now to find out why the sequence was so wrong...